# can't find Dark souls 2 DLC

Tags: dark-souls-2

i'm trying to buy dark souls 2 The Lost Crowns trilogy ( sunken crown ETC) from The PlayStation network store but i can't find it on the store. i have the normal edition of the game how do i find the it in store?

Answer (score 2):

On PS3, open the store and select the magnifier symbol at the top of the screen to search the store. Type in "Dark Souls 2" and select the game. On the game's page, select "Add-ons", where you will find the Season Pass, which includes all three add-ons for a reduced price, or all add-ons separately.

Alternatively, you can buy them on a PC, by logging in with your PSN account on [store.playstation.com](http://store.playstation.com) and searching for Dark Souls 2 there. The purchased content will then be added to your download list that you can access on PS3 by selecting "Account Management" --> "Transaction Management" --> "Download List".

Comment: when i search for dark souls 2 only the scholar of the first sin edition appears.

Comment: @Blank I just checked and it should also display the base game with add-ons. From what region is your PSN account?

Comment: what do you mean by region?

Comment: From what country is your PSN account, like USA, England, Germany etc. They have different stores.

Comment: my account should be Australia

Comment: The scholar of the first sin edition is a separate game on the store. Did you type in "Dark Souls 2" in the search and not find anything like "Season Pass" or just "Dark Souls 2" without "scholar of the first sin"? Also, try to log in at store.playstation.com and search there. It's the official store site. I have a UK account and everything is still there. I can unfortunately not see the Australian store because you can only see the store of your own region there.

Comment: and when i search for dark souls 2 that's all that comes up .if i buy it on store.playstation.com will i be able to download it on my ps3?

Comment: @Blank If you use the same PSN account as you use on your PS3, yes. It gets added to your download list as I wrote in the second paragraph of my answer. I did this before with PS Plus games. You should also find the add-ons on your PS3 store though if you can find them on the PC store.